# Can a coven be formed with two hags and a changeling?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am rewriting a NPC changeling. I would like to include it in a coven with two hags. However, the rule implies 3 hags:

> ## [Hag Covens](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/hag/)
>
> When three hags of any type gather, they can form a coven to gain increased magical ability. Any combination of hags can form a coven, but green hags are the most common members of such foul gatherings.

A changeling is a half-hag:

> ## [Changelings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-changeling/)
>
> Changelings are the offspring of hags and their lovers taken through magic or madness. Dropped off on doorsteps of prospective foster parents, changelings are raised by strangers.

I think it should be enough. Is there any rule or faq about this?

Note, that a solution would be to give the hex [Coven](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-coven-ex/) through a level of witch or magus. This is not my question though.

---

If a changeling is half a hag, my math teacher would say that you need two hags and two changelings ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Merely being a changeling: No.

Normally, changellings are *not* hags and do not count as one for any purposes related to game mechanics. Just like aasimars are not angels and tieflings are not demons.

But a changelling [sorcerer](http://archivesofnethys.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Accursed) could (or magus, or witch, as you pointed out), since they can gain the ability to count as a hag for the purposes of forming a coven.

### Changeling covens

Yep, those are a thing. Those are covens formed mostly by changelings, not hags, and show up on the [Blood of the Coven Player Companion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9wn2?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Blood-of-the-Coven) (pg. 13):

> The hag blood coursing through changelings’ veins makes
>   them especially adept at coven magic. Changeling witches
>   with the coven hex (Pathfinder RPG Advanced Player’s Guide
>   66) can form covens of three changelings without the usual
>   need for a hag member. But as a changeling draws upon
>   the power of her heritage, the call to wander into her hag
>   mother’s clutches becomes more persistent; changelings
>   who form a coven only with other changelings take a
>   –1 penalty on Will saving throws due to this increased stress.
>
> Changeling witches with the coven hex who wish to form
>   a coven must perform a 1-hour ritual. When the ritual is
>   complete, the changeling coven gains access to the following
>   spell-like abilities based on the witch level of their lowest level
>   participant.

Additionally to changelings witches, non-witches may take the *Coven-Touched* feat, which allows them to fill a spot in a coven even without the normal requirements:

> **Coven-Touched**
>
> You have a natural affinity for coven magic.
>
> Prerequisites: Cha 11, changeling.
>
> Benefit: You can join a changeling coven even if you are
>   not a witch with the coven hex. Your effective witch level
>   is equal to half your character level. A changeling coven
>   must still include at least one changeling witch who has
>   the coven hex.
>
> Additionally, select a single a 0-level spell drawn from the
>   witch’s spell list. You gain the ability to cast this spell three
>   times per day as a spell-like ability with a caster level equal
>   to your character level. The save DC for this spell is 10 + your
>   Intelligence modifier.

Note that this feat allows them to join *changeling covens* not *hag covens*.

But no, changelings are not *creatures that can join a coven*, as pointed out by the **Grand Coven** ritual on that same book:

> The newcomer must be a creature that could normally join a coven, such as a hag or a witch with the coven hex.

In addition to witches, magi and sorcerers, the book also presents a cleric archetype, the [Triadic Priest](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo-cleric-archetypes/triadic-priest-cleric-archetype/), who may pick the witch's coven hex as one of their abilities.